# How to interpret Python syntax for if else block

Tags: python

Below is an easy level coding problem, based on string manipulation:-

[image: Question]

I was able to solve it using a `for` loop by defining conditions for positive and negative numbers.

But while going through other solutions, I found this interesting solution in Python for the same question.

I have been working in Python for the past year but this is my first time coming across the below syntax for if else block

`if [str(x) > A[i], str(x) < A[i]][A[0] == '-']:`

Below is the complete code :

```
def maxValue(self, A, x):
        for i in xrange(len(A)):
            if [str(x) > A[i], str(x) < A[i]][A[0] == '-']:
                return A[:i] + str(x) + A[i:]
        return A + str(x)
```

How can I interpret this block? Where can I find documentation for it?

Comment: It's not any kind of new syntax, it's just unconventional use of something you already know. What does `[]` in term position do? What does `[]` in postfix position do? What do booleans do when coerced to `int`?

Comment: Sorry didn't get you exactly

Comment: That's an old style: `X if C else Y` which is written as `[Y, X][C]`. Note that in this form both X and Y are evaluated which does not occur in the if expression.

Comment: So basically `X if C else Y` and [Y, X][C]` are functionally different when it comes to execution? First expression is much more safer then, right?

Comment: Thanks DanD and hobbs for your insights. I completely understood the scenarios and even got some additional info on how can this be different for python 2.x and python 3.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The less hacky way to write it:

```
def maxValue(self, A, x):
    for i in xrange(len(A)):        
        if (A[0] == '-' and str(x) < A[i]) or (A[0] != '-' and str(x) > A[i]):
            return A[:i] + str(x) + A[i:]
    return A + str(x)
```

Explanation: if checks one of `[str(x) > A[i], str(x) < A[i]]` array values depending on condition `A[0] == '-'`.

If `A[0] == '-'` is `False`, it turns into `0`, thus gets `[str(x) > A[i], str(x) < A[i]][0]` and checks `str(x) > A[i]` condition.

If `(A[0] == '-') == True`, `True` turns to `1` and checks `[str(x) > A[i], str(x) < A[i]][1]` or `str(x) < A[i]`.

Comment: Will it be same for python 2.x and python 3.x

Comment: @AlokRaj Yes, you can test with `print([2, 3][False] == 2 and [2, 3][True] == 3)`

Comment: Got the solution, but thanks for insights :)  In python 2.x, True and False can be reassigned but In Python 3.x True and False are keywords and will always be equal to 1 and 0. It's a really small but awesome concept :D